# Triple integral limits

Tags: calculus

To find the volume created by the overlapping regions 
$$a\le\sqrt{xy}\le b\;,\;\; a\le\sqrt{xz}\le b\;,\;\; a\le\sqrt{yz}\le b$$

I have no idea what limits to use since you can't write one variable in terms of the other two. So how do I find the limits for this triple integral?

Answer (score 1):

$$a\le\sqrt{xy}\le b\;,\;\; a\le\sqrt{xz}\le b\;,\;\; a\le\sqrt{yz}\le b\Longleftrightarrow a^2\le xy\,,\,xz\,,\,yz\le b^2$$

So for example, we have that

$$a^2\le xy\le b^2\Longrightarrow \begin{cases}\frac{a^2}{x}\le y\le\frac{b^2}{x}&\;\;,\;\;\;x\ge 0\\{}\\\frac{b^2}{x}\le y\le \frac{a^2}{x}&\;\;,\;\;\;x<0\end{cases}$$

and we have, on the $\,xy$-plane,  a zone delimited by two hyperbolas...

Comment: So if I integrate with respect to z then y then x, I have limits a^2/y to b^ 2/y, then a^2/x to b^2/x but then for the x integral how do I find limits which are constants?